# JMeter Custom Plugin Variable Substitution

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

**Context**

I am developing a custom JMeter plugin which generates test data dynamically from a tree like structure.

The editor for the tree generates GUI input fields as needed, and therefore I have no set of defined configuration properties which are set in the respective `TestElement`. Instead, I serialize the tree as a whole in the GUI class, set the result as one property and deserialize it in the config element where it is processed further during test execution.

**Problem**

This works just fine, except that JMeter variable/function expressions like `${foo}` or `${_bar(..)}` in the dynamic input fields are not evaluated. As far as I understand the JMeter source code, the evaluation is triggered somehow if the respective property setters in `org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement` are used which is not possible for my plugin.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a proper implementation which can be used in my config element to evaluate such expressions explicitly after deserialization.

**Question**

I need a pointer to JMeter source code or documentation for evaluating variable/function expressions explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

After I manages to setup the JMeter-Project properly in my IDE, I found `org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable` which can be used like this:

```java
CompoundVariable compoundVariable = new CompoundVariable();
compoundVariable.setParameters("${foo}");

// returns the value of the expression in the current context
compoundVariable.execute();
```

Comment: i got super lucky you decided to document this here. would have taken me a while